# Restore JIRA from native instance to docker container

Tags: docker, jira, jira-plugin

Currently, I am using JIRA native instance. Now I want to convert it into docker container. Can anyone suggest me a way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can definitely restore JIRA native into a docker container using docker.**

## **Steps:**

- Backup existing JIRA
- Launch a JIRA dockerized
- Restore new JIRA

### - Backup existing JIRA

- Navigate to https://YOUR_SERVER.atlassian.net/secure/admin/CloudExport.jspa
- Choose Backup for cloud
- You will get a zip, unzip it under the folder `backup`.

### - Launch a JIRA dockerized

Use a [community image](https://hub.docker.com/r/cptactionhank/atlassian-jira-software) as official image don't exist yet

```
docker run --name jira --detach --publish 8080:8080 cptactionhank/atlassian-jira-software:latest
```

- Install using the options you want

### - Restore new JIRA

Copy the entities.xml to be ready to restore it:

```
cd backup
# copy inside of the docker
docker cp entities.xml jira:/var/atlassian/jira/import/
```

Navigate to http://localhost:8080/secure/admin/XmlRestore!default.jspa
- Type entities.xml in the `File Name`field
- Press Restore
- It might take time if it's big
Done!

### Improvement

Use a volume if you want to keep your data persistent:

```
docker run -v jira_data:/var/atlassian ...
```

Comment: https://YOUR_SERVER.atlassian.net/secure/admin/CloudExport.jspa is having an error as "Page unavailable".

Comment: You have to replace YOUR_SERVER by your JIRA native instance url. It is your url to your actual JIRA + `/secure/admin/CloudExport.jspa`

Comment: Getting following error - 
"Oops, you've found a dead link."

Comment: You already have an existing JIRA right?. Go to settings and find the backup parameters.